# SSH onto SynologyDSM - DSM5.2

Tags: ssh, synology

I am trying to SSH onto my new SynologyDSM (running DSM 5.2).  I have enabled SSH of course and authentication succeeds but then something is 'permission denied' and I have no idea how to debug this?

```
$ ssh myles@192.168.1.47 -v
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.47 [192.168.1.47] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.47:22 as 'myles'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:G1xPBYwXvIQ7AupjABvq21fGdrLYB2DtTy9+MOhzd88
debug1: Host '192.168.1.47' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mylesmcdonnell/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myles@192.168.1.47's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
myles@192.168.1.47's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.47 ([192.168.1.47]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.1.47 closed.
Transferred: sent 3200, received 2352 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 72132.1, received 53017.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: are you able to ssh in as root (use the Admin password)?

Comment: No, same issue.  My account is admin too.

Comment: Well, I mean the built in admin account, not an "administrative" account, but if that fails, I'd recommend trying another client. which one are you using? PuTTY? If it fails out of the box, then contacting Synology may not be a bad idea. you don't have a line in your ssh_config that says `PasswordAuthentication no` ?